# class member which is pointer to another class , c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, vector

can s.one please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong in this process, so that I don't have access to my vector "vect"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A 
{
private :

public :
    A() {}

};

class B 
{

private :
    std::vector<A*> vect;

public :
    B() {}
    void func(){

    std::cout << vect.size() <<std::endl;
    }
};


class C 
{
private :
    B* b ;

public :
    C() { }
    void func (){

    b->func();
    }
};


int main (){
    C c;
    c.func();

    return 0 ;

}
```

I expect to get  "0"  as an output but it seems like the vector hasn't been acceded so I get unrelevant number "17591314330723" !!!!

Comment: You're fortunate your program runs at all, instead of immediately crashing. Can you point to me the exact line in the shown code that sets the `b` pointer in your class to point to an instance of class `B` that exists, at that time, and which continues to exist when its `func`() method gets invoked?

Comment: An example of the virtue in compiling with all warnings enabled. For instance: [*"warning: 'c.C::b' is used uninitialized in this function"*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2aa842260058066).

Comment: try creating an instance of B so that you don't have undefined behavior

Comment: Why are you messing around with pointers at all?

Comment: @molbdnilo Actually it's just a test code , I need to do this process in my original code cause there I need to keep my vector of objects in secondary class.

Answer (score 1):

```
class C 
{
private :
    B* b ;

public :
    C() { }
    void func (){
        b->func();
    }
};
```

Looking at just this class; you can see that b is never assigned.  In addition to that it's a pointer.  This means that when you call `b->func()` you're trying to call `func()` on a random piece of memory.  This is undefined behavior and you're unlucky that it didn't just crash (since it hides the problem).

Your options are to either assign b to a value; which I'm not going to explain how to do; your C++ book should cover that; or to change it to be not a pointer; (ie remove the `*`) which will create a new B for you when you create a C.